Generating a numpy array containing its elements' coordinate vectors:
I would like to generate arrays of shape (n,)*n whose elements are the elements' own coordinate vectors. For example the n=2 case is:
array([[[0,0], [0,1]],
       [[1,0], [1,1]]])

Currently I have the code:
def coords(n):
    M = numpy.fromfunction(
        function = lambda *i: list(i),
        shape = (n,)*n
    )
    return M

However, this outputs a list of n arrays, each of shape (n,)*n , where the mth array is a projection of the mth coordinate. For example, for coords(2) this outputs:
[array([[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]),
 array([[0., 1.],
        [0., 1.]])]

... so the first array is a projection of the x coordinate, and the second array is a projection of the y coordinate.
I believe that this is because lambda functions cannot have vector outputs? If so, what else aside from a lambda function could I use inside of the numpy.fromfunction expression? Should I be using something entirely different from numpy.fromfunction ?
Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

There are various ways of generating the indices.  A nice one is nonzero
In [9]: x = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2); x
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

Since all terms are nonzero, we can be a pair of index arrays with:
In [10]: idx = np.nonzero(x); idx
Out[10]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64))

A nice thing about this tuple is it can be used directly to index the array:
In [11]: x[idx]
Out[11]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

The np.transpose of that tuple looks like:
In [12]: np.argwhere(x)
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)

That can't be used directly to index x.  You either have to iterate the rows to get values one by one, or make a tuple of the two columns - which is what idx already was.
To get your desired 3d array we can reshape this (4,2) array to:
In [13]: np.argwhere(x).reshape(2,2,2)
Out[13]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]]], dtype=int64)

The other answer suggests starting with indices, which gives the arrays, but in a different arrangement:
In [14]: np.indices((2,2))
Out[14]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])

To recover the original values we have to use something like:
In [16]: x[Out[13][:,:,0], Out[13][:,:,1]]
Out[16]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

Again this is separating out the row and column indices.
ix_
You can also index all elements with a pair of broadcastable arrays.  They don't have both be (2,2). A (2,1) and a (1,2) will work just as well.
In [17]: I,J = np.ix_(np.arange(2),np.arange(2))

In [18]: I,J
Out[18]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1]]))

In [19]: x[I,J]
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])


It's a list because you returned a list from your function. For your use case, there's no need to use a function, you can just directly transpose array's indices:
np.transpose(np.indices((2, 2)), axes=(1, 2, 0))

#array([[[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]],

#       [[1, 0],
#        [1, 1]]])

Or for nxn array, you can use rollaxis:
n = 2
np.rollaxis(np.indices((n,)*n), 0, -1)
#array([[[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]],

#       [[1, 1],
#        [0, 1]]])

